# How can I get thumbnail of youtube video on my application in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, youtube

My apps returned for user some links video on youtube. But I don't know how to get thumbnail of video. When user click to thumbnail it will call WebBrowserTask  to show this link.
Can you help me slove it. Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [GDATA](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/) to go and get information about youtube videos

If you want to half-ass it, the URI to a thumbnail will be:

http://img.youtube.com/vi/{0}/0.jpg

Where {0} is the ID of the video.