# How to get title of video on Youtube in Windows Phone apps?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, youtube-api

I have an app on Windows Phone. In my apps, I show some videos on youtube. when users click on the thumbnail of video, it will navigate to youtube link on browser. I found how to get thumbnail of youtube video in here [How can I get thumbnail of youtube video on my application in windows phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131693/how-can-i-get-thumbnail-of-youtube-video-on-my-application-in-windows-phone-7/10139218#10139218) and now I want to get title of video?
Please show me how to solve it?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this [GetVideoTitle](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/84903/Downloading-Youtube-Videos-C-WinForm), they use dll, which contains function 'GetVideoTitle'

Comment: They worked with WinForms, but  i think you can use dll, in your aim