# Get thumbnail from Youtube and save

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, youtube-api

I want to give a videoId to Youtube API and get thumbnails to save in my folder.

http://img.youtube.com/vi/VideoId/3.jpg  gives us thumbnail but how can save it?

That is to say; I have a textbox which I will write YoutubevideoId and after that by clicking a button I want to get thumbnail and save it to a physical folder.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702031/get-thumbnail-image-of-video-file-in-c-sharp and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131693/how-can-i-get-thumbnail-of-youtube-video-on-my-application-in-windows-phone-7

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get thumbnail of YouTube video link using YouTube API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-to-get-thumbnail-of-youtube-video-link-using-youtube-api)

Comment: Are there any c# function which takes jpg link and save it to the physical foldeR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go my friend

```
WebClient cli = new WebClient();

var imgBytes = cli.DownloadData("http://img.youtube.com/vi/VideoId/3.jpg");

File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Folder\file.jpg", imgBytes);
```

C# has a class named [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it has a method `DownloadData` which allows you to download content from the internet...

So, by creating an instance of it and calling `DownloadData` passing the URL I want to download the bytes you can get the bytes you need.

Now, you can use [`File.WriteAllBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which will write the bytes to a file in your disk.

Comment: Note that http://img.youtube.com/vi/VideoId/3.jpg is NOT returning a valid thumbnail. To get the REAL thumbnail of the video use replace the ``3.jpg`` with ``hqdefault.jpg``.  So it looks like this:

http://img.youtube.com/vi/VideoId/hqdefault.jpg